# Domain is whitelisted for summary_large_image card, but Twitter is not displaying the image

Tags: twitter-card, twitter-integration

I have added all meta tags, but the image is not displaying:

[image]

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@Welfies_sports" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Welfies.com | Login" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Welfies.com is an Exclusive dedicated social network for sports uniting the world of sports and related activities. Welfies.com is first of its kind which allows sports enthusiasts to show up, share, understand, play, nearby players, clubs and much more in one plate. Welfies.com is first of its kind which allows sports enthusiasts to show up, share, understand, play and much more under one roof" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://www.welfies.com/images/logo/tw_logo.png" />
<meta name="twitter:url" content="https://www.welfies.com/login" />
```

Comment: can you list examples of the meta tags?

Comment: Edit the post with your meta tags included so that we can see if it was done correctly. It's also possible that Twitter needs some time to validate the content of your site. I think it's possible that they may block some meta image/video from new sites to prevent spam/nsfw content

Comment: I have entered the meta tags which I used.Please help to resolve the error.